# What I should send to a JavaScript front end (client) after a user authentication

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry, I'm having a mental block: I'm not sure what I should send to a JavaScript front end (client) after a user authentication on the server. I know that there needs to be some controls for the user (user/admin)to click but I'm not sure what to send that's secure and what not to send that's not secure. I've been told hidden controls are not secure. I know how to implement user authentication on the server. I understand a check on the server needs to be made if a control is clicked to check if the user (user/admin) has the right permissions for that control before the server executes the control function (on the server). I know I can set a variable and send it to the front end, once it's received (Ajax response) add controls (appendChild). If I do it this way, I feel it's not secure because all the code to do this is easily viewable by the browser (page source).

Comment: Isi t a single page client?

Answer (score 1):

Permission checking is on the server side, so even if code is viewable why you afraid about this?

After success login action you can send cookie to store session on client side or JavaScript variable if this is Single Page Application.

On the other hand - after login you can redirect to secure place and present HTML with all necessary inputs / fields. Users without login won't see secured templates.

But always remember to do not trust any data from client, checking permission on back-end side is only one good thing.

Comment: So sending and setting a variable on the client side (JavaScript) is secure? Example: If I have a variable called accountType on the client that can have one of two values (client/admin). Depending on the value of the accountType variable determines what controls are available to users (client) and different controls for admin (admin).

Comment: Browser / client should to know in some way what to render. You can secure connection with SSL, but even witch that - you shouldn't believe to any data from client and always validate / check permissions. You can also validate session (by AJAX) from time to time and redirect to login page if you suspect that user hasn't enough privileges.